# LogicApp liquid transform using minus operator

Tags: json, transform, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I have a Liquid transform JSON-JSON. I have the following:

```
{
   "totalCount": {{15 | minus:1 }} 
}
```

But i'm getting

```
 "totalCount": 15
```

and not

```
"totalCount": 14
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. It should be uppercase "M" in minus

```
{
   "totalCount": {{15 | Minus:1 }} 
}
```